# switchMap operator doesn't execute the returned observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, nestjs, typeorm

I have an API (NestJS) and trying to build a login. It is using TypeOrm to access DB.

When the strategy class calls `auth.validateUser` method, I need to get a user from DB and compare the passwords using `bcrypt`. The problem is that `switchMap` is not subscribing to the returned observable.

Here's my code:

**auth.service.ts**

```js
validateUser(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.userService.readByEmail(email).pipe(
        switchMap(user => {
            return new Observable<User>(subscriber => {
                if (!user) {
                    subscriber.next(null)
                    subscriber.complete()
                } else {
                    bcrypt.compare(password + global.userPepper, user.password)
                        .then(result => {
                            const { password, ...validUser } = user
                            if (result) subscriber.next(validUser as User)
                            else subscriber.next(null)
                            subscriber.complete()
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log(err)
                            subscriber.next(null)
                            subscriber.complete()
                        })
                }
            })
        })
    )
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```js
readByEmail(email: string): Observable<User> {
    return new Observable<User>(subscriber => {
        // This part of the code is never executed
        this.userRepo.findOne({ email }).then(user => subscriber.next(user))
    })
}
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

**UPDATE:**
The problem in `userService.readByEmail` was solved following the suggestions from [Tobias S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8613630/tobias-s) answer.
But the `switchMap` operator from `authService` was not being called. I solved it changing the strategy file, which calls my `auth.validateUser`, to return a promise and not a observable anymore and works.
`local.strategy.ts`
Before:

```js
validate(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.auth.validateUser(email, password).pipe(
        map(user => {
            if (!user) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException()
            }

            return user
        })
    )
}
```

After:

```js
validate(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.auth.validateUser(email, password).pipe(
        map(user => {
            if (!user) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException()
            }

            return user
        })
    ).toPromise()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code could be simplified a lot more. You don't really need to create any Observables yourself with `new Observable()`.

In UserService you can simply create an Observable from the Promise with the `from` operator.

**user.service.ts**

```
readByEmail(email: string): Observable<User> {
    return from(this.userRepo.findOne({ email }))
}
```

In AuthService you can return `EMPTY` if there is no user and then return the Promise you are creating with bcrypt.

> "[If it accepts Observable, it accepts Promise](https://benlesh.medium.com/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875)"

**auth.service.ts**

```
validateUser(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.userService.readByEmail(email).pipe(
        switchMap(user => {
            if (!user) return EMPTY

            return bcrypt.compare(password + global.userPepper, user.password)
                .then(result => {
                    const { password, ...validUser } = user
                    if (result) return validUser as User
                 })
                .catch(console.log)
        })
    )
}
```

Comment: findOne in userService.readByEmail was executed. But any pipe was not. I tried to log readByEmail and switchMap from validateUser to see if it is running, but only in the first case I get a log. Is another operator more appropriate?